# Supabase: PostgreSQL policy using a column value gives error

Tags: postgresql, supabase

I am trying to set a Row Level Security policy in PostgreSQL via Supabase.

The table has two relevant fields: access (either "P" for public or "R" for restricted) and include (an array of email ids). I wish to set a policy which allows all authenticated users to access the records which are either "P" or if "R" their email must be present.

```
CREATE POLICY "policy_name"
ON public.table
FOR SELECT
TO authenticated 
USING (
  access = "P" OR
  auth.email() = ANY(include)
);
```

This gives an error saying `Column "P" does not exist`
I am new to SQL expressions and will appreciate any help. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The error was because I used **double quotes**!!!!

The policy that works in supabase is:

```
(((jwt() ->> 'email'::text) = ANY (include)) OR (access = 'P'::text) OR (uid() = user_id))
```

1. Changed the `auth.email() to jwt() ->> 'email'` since the former is being deprecated.
2. I added the last `uid() = user_id` (a column in the table) without which it would not permit the user to add a record